# Spark Streaming - Job Duration vs Submitted

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am trying to optimize a Spark Streaming application which collects data from a Kafka cluster, processes it and saves the results to various database tables. The Jobs tab in the Spark UI shows the duration of each job as well as the time it was submitted.

I would expect that for a specific batch, a job starts processing when the previous job is done. However, in the attached screenshot, the  "Submitted" time of a job is not right after the previous job finishes. For example, job 1188 has a duration of 1 second and it was submitted at 12:02:12. I would expect that the next job would be submitted one second later, or at least close to it, but instead it was submitted six seconds later.

[image]

Any ideas on how this delay can be explained? These jobs belong to the same batch and are done sequentially. I know that there is some scheduling delay between jobs and tasks, but I would not expect it to be that large. Moreover, the Event Timeline of a Stage does not show large Scheduling Delay.

I am using Pyspark in a Standalone mode.

Comment: Let's reverse the question - why do you expect to be no delay? Do you see any jobs lagging? Is the processing time longer than batch duration? Also some code would be useful so what we know what we are dealing with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since these two jobs are sequential and the driver does not do anything significant in between, I would expect to be some minor delay for the scheduling part. But since a job's duration is around 1 second, a delay of 5 seconds seems too large to me. The processing time is not larger than the batch duration, but I am trying to optimize it. Posting code is not straightforward, I can post later, but conceptually these two jobs take the same dataframe for input, perform different aggregations each and save the result to the database.